# Is hashing output is by-default hex encoded

Tags: security, hash, cryptography

As md5 hashing algorithm generate string length of 128 bits( =16 bytes)
&
sha256 hashing algorithm generate string of length of 256 bits ( =32 bytes).

```
bash-3.2$ md5 <<< 'hash'
4e76434eea3c9d9cf9cb10bbf3f4a74b // string with 32 chareacter.
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ shasum -a 256 <<< 'hash'
4e5e494fa316ffc82b8252b23524f1433639858267d641c1217059dc4403e045  // string with 64 chareacter.
bash-3.2$
```

Based on output.

> md5 generate 32 characters hex string & sha256 generate 64 characters hex string.

Here my assumption is, **Hashing output are always encoded with *hex* encoding.** as output string is double in payload size for given hashing algorithm and contains only hex encoded allowed characters.

Is my assumption is correct ?

Comment: An hash is a sequence of bits. For human consumption it is easier to represent or output it as a sequence of hexadecimal digits

Comment: *Is my assumption correct?* No.

Comment: Hashes are very often base64 encoded. For example, commit hash in git.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, In reference of given example in question, Why md5 generate 32 character string ? it should generate 16 bytes. 
same with sha256 also.
Did i misinterpreted something here ?

Answer (score 0):

The hash is often displayed as hex string and often also stored as such but it may also be stored simply as binary data in a buffer or even as large integer internally because in essence it's just a large number.

When you process it, always check the output and input for the libraries/code you use to make sure they produce/expect the same format, otherwise you'll need to take care of encoding or decoding yourself.